# SQL select statement where the text I am looking for has single quotes

Tags: sql-server, select, sql-like, double-quotes, single-quotes

I am trying to do a select statement in Microsoft SQL server management studio.  The data looks like this:

[image: snapshot of data]

My select statement is:

```
SELECT * FROM OSUSR_W7I_INVENTORYCHANGELOG 
WHERE OBJECTTYPEID = 3
and CREATEDBY is null
and TEXT = 'State changed from ''Awaiting Prep'' to ''Import Error'''
```

But this brings back no results, despite there being lots of records with this text.

I was able to retrieve some data by using this statement:

```
SELECT * FROM OSUSR_W7I_INVENTORYCHANGELOG 
WHERE OBJECTTYPEID = 3
and CREATEDBY is null
and TEXT like '%Awaiting Prep%'
and TEXT like '%Import Error%'
```

but unfortunately it brings back too many results because it is bringing back data that states: 'State changed from 'Import Error' to 'Awaiting Prep''
where I am only looking for 'State changed from 'Awaiting Prep' to 'Import Error''

Please can anyone help.  From reading other posts putting a double quote in should solve the issue of the single quotes but in this instance it doesn't work.
Many thanks

Comment: Are you sure the reason your first example isnt working is because there is some whitespace at the end? What is the datatype of `TEXT` field?

Comment: Pull the actual text from a row and see what is actually there. To my eyes looking at your image there seem to be more than a single space between `from` and the opening quote, and there may be other places with additional spaces you've not accounted for.

Comment: Hi Jamiec, there are no white spaces at the end.  The datatype of the field is nvarchar.

Comment: Hi Damien_The_Unbeliever, There are 2 spaces between from and 'Awaiting, there are 2 spaces before 'to' and 2 spaces after 'to' put I have included them spaces in my statement and still I am getting no results.

Comment: *I have included them spaces in my statement* - not in the sql you've put in your question you havent

Comment: Hi Jamiec, no, I didn't have those spaces in my original post but had tried it previously as I simply copied and pasted the text into my statement and simply added the extra quotes.  I also tried it again at the request of Damien, just to be sure, and it still didn't work.   Luckily there are only a few set statements that can appear in the TEXT column so that's why Phaen's suggestion worked for me.  If there were other instances of those 2 phrases then yes I would still be stuck.  I cant understand why double quotes don't work in this case!

Comment: @EmmaCurzon they do work - I tested it on SQL2016 but that functionality has not changed in at least the past 5 versions of SQL. Youve chosen a band-aid solution and not solved the real problem. It may never cause an issue, or one day it'll come back and bite you on the arse.

Comment: Hi Jamiec, I am using SQL 2017 version 17.2.  Any suggestions on why the double commas aren't working for me then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine your LIKE to one using % as placeholders, instead of:

```
SELECT * FROM OSUSR_W7I_INVENTORYCHANGELOG 
WHERE OBJECTTYPEID = 3
and CREATEDBY is null
and TEXT like '%Awaiting Prep%'
and TEXT like '%Import Error%'
```

do:

```
SELECT * FROM OSUSR_W7I_INVENTORYCHANGELOG 
WHERE OBJECTTYPEID = 3
and CREATEDBY is null
and TEXT like '%Awaiting Prep%Import Error%'
```

Comment: This will cause you only to retrieve the desired 'State changed from 'Awaiting Prep' to 'Import Error' rows only, but vote it down for no reason..

Comment: *This will cause you only to retrieve the desired* - not true. It will also retrieve `fooAwaiting PrepbarImport Errortuu`

Comment: @EmmaCurzon lets hope you dont have any records like "Failed to update state from......"

Comment: As % are placeholders, ofcourse it will allow anything else to be found that contains 'Awaiting Prep' and 'Import Error' in this sequence. But if he was just looking for exactly that string he would not need any placeholders and could just filter for exactly that string ..?

Comment: @phaen (hint: Emma is a girl's name). Wasnt the exact question how to "Filter for exactly that string"?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using LTRIM and RTRIM in sql server. If there is case of some white space. Otherwise your statement is seems ok

```
SELECT * FROM OSUSR_W7I_INVENTORYCHANGELOG 
WHERE OBJECTTYPEID = 3
and CREATEDBY is null
and LTRIM(RTRIM(TEXT)) = 'State changed from ''Awaiting Prep'' to ''Import 
Error'''
```

Comment: Hi Anubrij, I tried this but it did not work.  I still got no results.